# ERROR: Executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I've seen the same error in multiple questions on stackoverflow, but all of the problems are from people not putting the correct path such as putting the path to the directory and not the executable. I have my path pointing to the executable but for some reason it still gives me that error?
Here's the code that's causing the problem\

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path.realpath("phantomjs.exe"))
elif sys.platform == "darwin":
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path.realpath("phantomjsMac"))
else:
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path.realpath("phantomjsLinux"))
```

Comment: Can you show us what is `path.realpath` all about?

Comment: @DebanjanB Somebody suggested that I put that there so they knew I had the correct path. Basically just the path to the executable.